# Why is model variables initialization method called twice in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to figure out the implementation of SGD in tensorflow.

In the `apply_gradients` [method](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/da6568a4d354c8863ecbb8991817e546c5f361e5/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L593)

```
with ops.name_scope_v2(self._name):
  # Create iteration if necessary.
  with ops.init_scope():
    self._create_all_weights(var_list)
```

just before `self._create_all_weights(var_list)` I added some logging

```
with ops.name_scope_v2(self._name):
  # Create iteration if necessary.
  with ops.init_scope():
    tf.print('apply_gradients::with ops.init_scope: ', var_list[0].numpy(), var_list[1].numpy())
    self._create_all_weights(var_list)
```

and then I got the initialized weights and bias **twice**, which I don't understand. Why is this method called twice?

To verify my guess, I disabled all my logging except

```
  def apply_gradients(self,
                      grads_and_vars,
                      name=None,
                      experimental_aggregate_gradients=True):
  tf.print('apply_gradients is called')
```

just before [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/012a464f1f3bacfda29f52843835fae73cca0d77/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L630)

```
grads_and_vars = optimizer_utils.filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
```

each time I ran my script I got only one of that logging

```
apply_gradients is called
```

Why is weights and bias initialization method called twice in tensorflow?

[click here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wpSpgSi1fHi8Fr8CGgkFJDrZ1Ifh77JG?usp=sharing) to check the whole piece and reproduce my trial on colab

Comment: check this SO answer which may be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67799377/how-many-times-the-loss-function-is-triggered-from-fit-method-in-keras/67837016#67837016

Comment: I was not able to replicate the issue - could you share a code snippet?